# Bitwise Operator gives different result in playground

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

When I use the bitwise operator in the swift playground, 147 << 24 gives me 2,466,250,752. However, running the same operator on my iPhone and printing the results gives me -1828716544. Why should it give a different result and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a matter of 32-bit vs 64-bit integers, because the result of the
left shift `<<` is of the same type as its operands.

The Playground uses the 64-bit architecture, therefore

```
147 << 24 = 0x0000000000000093 << 24 = 0x0000000093000000 = 2466250752
```

On a 32-bit device, 147 is a 32-bit *signed* integer and therefore

```
147 << 24 = 0x00000093 << 24 = 0x93000000 = -1828716544
```

is negative (the sign bit is equal to 1).

However, the result fits into a 32-bit *unsigned* integer, so this
would give the same result on both architectures:

```
let x = UInt32(147) << 24 // 2466250752
```